# iOS - Frame Height not by Pixel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, frame, cgrect

I just had a question about the Frame Height.

frame.size.height = 450;

When I set a CGRect frame with height of 450 when the x= 0 and y = 0. The tableview extends almost all the way to the bottom. IS the number not based on pixels since I am testing it on an iPhone 5, the 1136. It shouldn't even have extended half way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS screen coordinates are in UI points. One point is one pixel on the original-density screens, and one point is thus two pixels on the high resolution/retina displays.

Update from 2014: One point is even three pixels on the iPhone 6 Plus. (2018: and iPhone 6s Plus, 7 Plus, 8 Plus and X.)

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing points and pixels.
See the Apple iOS documentation for more info.

> In iOS there is a distinction between the coordinates you specify in your drawing code and the pixels of the underlying device. When using native drawing technologies such as Quartz, UIKit, and Core Animation, the drawing coordinate space and the view’s coordinate space are both logical coordinate spaces, with distances measured in points. These logical coordinate systems are decoupled from the device coordinate space used by the system frameworks to manage the pixels onscreen.
>
> The system automatically maps points in the view’s coordinate space to pixels in the device coordinate space, but this mapping is not always one-to-one. This behavior leads to an important fact that you should always remember:
>
> One point does not necessarily correspond to one physical pixel.
> The purpose of using points (and the logical coordinate system) is to provide a consistent size of output that is device independent.

Answer (score 1):

As Jesper and Rikkles said, the iPhone 5 has a Retina display, which means that you have to double up the number of pixels that you set to match the number of pixels actually displayed on the screen.

Plus, don't forget that if your container view was designed for the original iPhone resolution (320x480), it may be resized when used on an iPhone 5, making your original "450" setting a 450/480*568 = 533 pixel height.

Comment: This is not default behavior, it's total depended on how you set the autoresizemask or if you use the auto resize properties.

Comment: This is the behavior for the root view of a view controller. Of course for other views you have to play with the `autoresizingMask` property of the view.

Comment: You can also due this for the view of the rootviewcontroller.